# React view is not rendering when using react router 4 and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I want to create simple example using React, React router 4, Redux.
But I'm stuck on rendering process.
Router User is rendering as normal but my Home view not.
Also I have no errors so I don't know were problem is.
Any help I would be very thankful.

Files:

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore,applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/rootReducer";
import { Provider } from"react-redux"
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { Home } from "./components/home/Home";
import { User } from "./components/user/User";

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
);

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    <Link to="/user">User</Link>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route exact path="/user" component={User}/>
                </div>
            </Router>
            </Provider>

        );
    }
}

render(<App/>,window.document.getElementById("app"));
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import userReducer from "./userReducer";

export default combineReducers({
   user:userReducer
});
```

**userReducer.js**

```
export default function User(state=[{name:'TMP'}],action={}){
    switch (action.type){
        default: return state
    }
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from"react-redux"
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                TADAAAAA HOME
                {user}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return{
        user:state.user
    }
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Home))
```

**user.js**

```
import React from "react";


export class User extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                USER
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You exported home as default instead of as Home. Change import to `{default as Home} ` or the export to a named export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Home } from "./components/home/Home";
```

should be:

```
import Home from "./components/home/Home";
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) you can learn about the differences of importing/exporting as default or not